# Disable and enable AWS lambda trigger programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way for us to disable & enable the Lambda trigger programmatically (e.g. for scheduled maintains purposes)?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

You can disable and enable Lambda triggers by using following approaches with **Update Event Source Mapping**, based on how you are going to do it.

- Using AWS CLI: You can use AWS CLI [update-event-source-mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html) command with `--enabled | --no-enabled` parameters.
- Using AWS SDK (E.g NodeJS): You can use AWS SDK [updateEventSourceMapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateEventSourceMapping-property) method with  `Enabled: true || false` attribute.
- Using AWS REST API: You can use AWS REST API [UpdateEventSourceMapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html) with `"Enabled": boolean` attributes.

Note: You need to grant relevant permission for each of the approach to execute using IAM Roles/Users or temporarily access credentials.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented under EventSourceMapping, you specify which event arn should map to a given lambda, it will do the trigger association.

Below is the API using node js,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#createEventSourceMapping-property

Using CLI:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html

All supported languages have this API as well.

Comment: I try using the `AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient().listEventSourceMappings()` and it returns an empty list. Doesn't seems like it? Or maybe it doesn't support S3 events?

Comment: Try the clip before you take it to code. There are other things you might be configured wrong.

Comment: Using EventSourceMapping won't work because those functions only work with Kinesis streams, SQS, and DynamoDB streams:

see the documentation for `listEventSourceMappings` under the input documentation for params:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listEventSourceMappings-property

I've tried to return all by not specifying a function ARN and only get those with SQS (I don't have any Kinesis or DynamoDB events), no SNS or others.

Answer (score 1):

Enable/Disable in Java:

```
AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().build();
UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest request = new UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest()
    .withUUID(uuid)
    .withFunctionName("myFunction")
    .withEnabled(true) // false to disable
    .withBatchSize(123);
UpdateEventSourceMappingResult response = client.updateEventSourceMapping(request);
```

In Kotlin:

```
val client: AWSLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().build()
val request: UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest = UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest()
                .withUUID(uuid)
                .withFunctionName("myFunction")
                .withEnabled(false) // true to enable
                .withBatchSize(10)
val response: UpdateEventSourceMappingResult = client.updateEventSourceMapping(request)
```

Dependency Needed:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

All credits to [@ashan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549165/ashan), for anyone like me who would prefer to have an example of how to do it using AWS cli, replace `$uuid` with your trigger UUID:

```
# Enable lambda polling & invocation
aws lambda update-event-source-mapping --uuid  "$uuid" --enabled

# Disable it
aws lambda update-event-source-mapping --uuid  "$uuid" --no-enabled
```