# Best way for a Lambda to start processing messages in a SQS Queue at a specific time of day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a SQS queue which fills up with messages throughout the day and I want to start processing all the messages at a specific time. The scenario would be:

1. Between 9AM and 5PM the queue would receive messages
2. At 6PM the messages should be processed by a lambda

I was thinking of:

1. **Enabler:** Lambda A which will be executed using a CloudWatch Event Bridge ruleat 6PM. This lambda would create a SQS trigger for Lambda C
2. **Disabler:** Lambda B which will be executed using a CloudWatch Event Bridge rule at 8PM . This lambda would remove the SQS trigger of Lambda C
3. **Executer:** Lambda C which process the messages in the queue

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Your architecture appears to be inappropriate. AWS Lambda functions are designed to react to events, such as a message being placed in a queue. This makes it an excellent choice for processing messages _immediately_ after messages become available. So, one option is **do not wait until 6pm**. You do not mention how many messages accumulate in the queue, so it's hard to know whether it is better to use an AWS Lambda function, or to simply launch an Amazon EC2 instance with code that processes the messages in the queue.

Comment: The total number of accumulated messages will be in the range of 35000 to 50000

Comment: Thank You. I am reevaluating my design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would aim for the process which requires the least complexity / smallest changes to your Lambda. You could use the AWS SDK to enable / disable your Lambda's subscription, rather than actually deleting and recreating it. See [this question on how to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199256/disable-and-enable-aws-lambda-trigger-programmatically/46386708) and specifically the `enabled` parameter in the [`updateEventSourceMapping()` method in the docs it links to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateEventSourceMapping-property):

> Enabled — (Boolean)
>
> When true, the event source mapping is active. When false, Lambda
> pauses polling and invocation.
>
> Default: True

The advantage is that the only thing you're changing is the `enabled` flag - everything else (the SQS-Lambda subscription, if you will) is unchanged.

---

This approach still has the danger that if the enabler/disabler lambda(s) fail, your processing will not occur during your target hours. Particularly, I'm not personally *super* confident in the success rate of AWS's self-mutating commands - this might just be my bias, but it definitely leans toward "infra changes tend to fail more often than regular AWS logic".

It's worth considering whether you really *need* this implementation, or whether the time-based aggregation can be done on the results (e.g., let this Lambda processing run on events as they come in and write the output to some holding pen, then at Xpm when you trust all events have come in, move the results for today from the holding pen into your main output).

This approach may be safer, in that a failed trigger on the "moving" step could be easier / faster to recover from than a failed trigger on the above "process all my data now" step, and it would not depend on changing the Lambda definition.

Comment: Thank You @MyStackRunnethOver

I am reevaluating my design