# AWS: Only invoke lambda during a specific timeframe each day

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I currently have a service that publishes a message to an SNS topic which has a subscription with name filter to add it to an SQS queue which ultimately triggers a lambda function.

I have a use-case for the same service to raise a message but for one specific filter name subscription to only invoke a lambda during a three-hour period 00:00 and 03:00. Out with of these hours, the messages should just backup and then redistribute the next day during this time window.

Is this possible, and how/what services are required to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by programmatically enabling/disabling the source mapping between the lambda and the queue. Following steps can be followed to achieve this:

[image]

1. Create an API gateway endpoint for enabling/disabling the source mapping. It can also be done programmatically using an additional lambda instead of API gateway.

   API gateway option : [https://harishkm.in/2020/07/18/enable-disable-aws-lambda-triggers-programmatically-by-invoking-an-api/#:~:text=Lambda%20functions%20can%20be%20triggered,Enabled%22%3A%20true%2Ffalse%20%7D](https://harishkm.in/2020/07/18/enable-disable-aws-lambda-triggers-programmatically-by-invoking-an-api/#:%7E:text=Lambda%20functions%20can%20be%20triggered,Enabled%22%3A%20true%2Ffalse%20%7D)

   Lambda Option: [Disable and enable AWS lambda trigger programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199256/disable-and-enable-aws-lambda-trigger-programmatically)
2. The next step will be to create two event bridge rules to start/stop the lambda that reads messages from the queue. In the specific case, **Enable Lambda trigger  rule** will enable the source mapping between the queue and the source lambda at 00:00. Whereas **Enable Lambda trigger  rule** will enable the source mapping between the queue and the source lambda at 03:00

Answer (score 0):

You can pause and later resume a Lambda's invocation from a queue using the [UpdateEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html) API.

Create a new NightQueue, which subscribes to the relevant pattern.  Create a Lambda handler and a [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) to poll NightQueue for messages.

Next create two EventBridge rules that [run on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html).  The OnRule is scheduled at `00:00` and the OffRule at `03:00`.  Create [targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html) for the rules, pointing to a Lambda function.  Set the target's event detail input to something like `{"action": "on"}` for OnRule.  When the Lambda receives a payload with `"on"` action from the OnRule, it enables NightQueue's event source mapping with a `UpdateEventSourceMapping` SDK call, setting `Enabled: true`.  When triggered by the OffRule (Lambda receives `{"action": "off"}` as the event input), the Lambda pauses the event source mapping with `Enabled: false` in the SDK call, with messages accumulating in NightQueue until the mapping is re-enabled the following night.

Note:  The [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) it can take up to 15 minutes for the enabling/disabling changes to take effect.